# Ajax/Json - How to save returning data in a variabe when column name is numeric?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

When trying to store a json value as a variable from a returning ajax ...

```
$.ajax({
url:'example.php',
type:'POST',
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){

    var checkname = data.name;  // working
    var check1m = data.1m;      // Here I get the SyntaxError

}
});
```

... and it's column name is starting with a number (e.g. 1m):

```
[{"name":"Peter","city":"London","1m":"not attending","2m":"attending"}]
```

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: identifier starts immediately after numeric literal
```

How can I store the value in the variable (check1m)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access value using `offset`.Like this..

```
 var check1m = data['1m'];
```

**Example**

```js
var json = [{"name":"Peter","city":"London","1m":"not attending","2m":"attending"}] ;
console.log(json[0]['1m']);
```

Answer (score 2):

simply just Use `data["1m"]` instead

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$.ajax({
url:'example.php',
type:'POST',
dataType: 'json',
success:function(data){

    var checkname = data[0]['name'];  // working
    var check1m = data[0]['1m'];      // Here I get the SyntaxError

}
});
```